# Laravel, how can I output multiple records of the same ID in a HMTL table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have a orderitems table which hasMany products. When I output the orderItems to a table it only shows it once. For example if I ordered a cheese a pizza it would only display one of them in the table, even though in PHPMyAdmin there are multiple records of the same pizza.

**Desired Output**
Display multiple products with the same product ID in the table instead of one.

**Controller**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderItemsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $orderItems = OrderItem::with('products_rel')->get();


    return view('basket', ['orderItems'=> $orderItems]);
    }

    public function  create()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function store ()
    {
    request()->validate([
        'product_id'=> 'required',

    ]);



    OrderItem::create([

        'product_id' =>request('product_id'),



    ]);


    }
```

**blade file**

```
<table id="checkout">
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Size</th>

<th>Price</th>
</tr>
@foreach($orderItems as $orderItem)
    @foreach($orderItem->products_rel as $related_product)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$related_product->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$related_product->size}}</td>

        <td>{{$related_product->price}}</td>
    </tr>


    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Products Table**

```
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('order_item_id');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->foreignId('topping_id')->nullable();



    });
}
```

**OrderItems table**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id');
       
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**orderItem Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Product;

class OrderItem extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;


    public function products_rel(){
      return $this-> hasMany(Product::class );

    }
    public function Order(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::Class);
}
}
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'item_name', 'size', 'toppings','price',
    ];

    public function orderItem() {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderItem::class,);

    }



}
```

**DD**
when I dd $orderItems all order items appear:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1069 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => App\Models\OrderItem {#1213 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "product_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2021-05-27 16:50:48"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-27 16:50:48"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => App\Models\OrderItem {#1214 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "product_id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2021-05-28 14:58:39"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-28 14:58:39"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    2 => App\Models\OrderItem {#1215 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "product_id" => 2
        "created_at" => "2021-05-28 15:23:34"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-28 15:23:34"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    3 => App\Models\OrderItem {#1216 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "product_id" => 2
        "created_at" => "2021-05-28 15:49:33"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-28 15:49:33"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    4 => App\Models\OrderItem {#1217 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "order_items"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "product_id" => 3
        "created_at" => "2021-05-28 15:49:37"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-28 15:49:37"
      ]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you please add the orderItem model

Comment: Do you get multiple result on `dd($orderItems);`?

Comment: @Espresso yeah, all the items appear there

Comment: @SVJ99 could you please add it

Comment: @omaresmaeel done added it in

Comment: @SVJ99, please show us your `orders` table and model.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa please  ignore them, I have not implemented them. Theyre going to be used to save all the order items into an order later on

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue

you're reversing the relation by adding the id of the product in the table of order item while you should be doing the opposite

when you create a new order item do it like that

```
$orderItemId = OrderItem::create([

    'product_id' =>request('product_id'),
])->id;
```

and then add this id to the product like this

```
$productIds = ['1','2',''3] // hybothitecal product ids, and it should come from the request
$products = Product::find($productIds)->map(function($product){$product->order_item_id = $orderItemId;
$product->save();});
```

and after that everything is going to work as expected *hopefully :'D *

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: what was the error? or it just didn't work

Comment: It just did the same results as before, All I need to do is output everything from the orderItem table into a html table. I don't understand why it is only outputting the 3 results

Comment: I think because now it's empty try to add one order item to some products, for now, you're adding one order item for one product so, it does the same as before 

but if you send an array of products and the orderItem Id to them. it will work fine ,
I have updated my answer

Comment: I found out the reason why.  It is outputting everything from the products table. I want it to output everything from the orderItems table, so maybe my relationship is wrong?

Comment: yes your relationship is wrong, and that what I was trying to solve all that time :'D,
you shouldn't have product_id in the order items table in the first place, you should assign the orderItem id to multiple products if you want to have every order item with its products 
I hope I was clear enough